# Typedef enum declaration: which is correct

Tags: objective-c, enums

So I been used to use this format to declare a enum types:

```
typedef enum SortType {
    SORT_BY_NAME,
    SORT_BY_COMPANY,
    SORT_BY_NONE
} SortType;
```

But I saw some people declare it this way

```
typedef enum {
    SORT_BY_NAME,
    SORT_BY_COMPANY,
    SORT_BY_NONE
} SortType;
```

Both seems to work and no error. But I want to know which is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SortType) {
    SortTypeName,
    SortTypeCompany,
    SortTypeNone
};
```

as per the Apple Developer Guides and Sample Code: [Adopting Modern Objective-C > Enumeration Macros](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

Between those two, there isn't a wrong form per se. That said, the current recommended way to declare enums in Objective-C is using the `NS_ENUM` macro:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SortType) {
    SORT_BY_NAME,
    SORT_BY_COMPANY,
    SORT_BY_NONE
};
```

From Apple's [Adopting Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW6) guide:

> The NS_ENUM and NS_OPTIONS macros provide a concise, simple way of defining enumerations and options in C-based languages. These macros improve code completion in Xcode and explicitly specify the type and size of your enumerations and options. Additionally, this syntax declares enums in a way that is evaluated correctly by older compilers, and by newer ones that can interpret the underlying type information.
>
> Use the NS_ENUM macro to define enumerations, a set of values that are mutually exclusive:
>
> The NS_ENUM macro helps define both the name and type of the enumeration, in this case named UITableViewCellStyle of type NSInteger. The type for enumerations should be NSInteger.